# Getting multiline nodes automatically with forest

Tags: forest

This defines a command that allows multiple lines within a forest node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand\nbox[1]{\begin{varwidth}{.5\textwidth}#1\end{varwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
[parent
  [\nbox{first\\child}]
  [\nbox{second\\child}]
  ]
  \end{forest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have this command inserted automatically into all
nodes, so it does not have to be repeated?  This would be useful where
all or almost all nodes have multiple lines.

Comment: Use ’\forestset{default preamble={...}}’.

Comment: Combine @SašoŽivanović's comment with marmot's answer if you want this for all trees in the document or use just marmot's answer to apply on a per-tree basis.

Answer (score 3):

You really do not need `varwidth` to have multiline nodes. `for tree={align=left}` does that already.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
  for tree={align=left}
[parent
  [{first\\child}]
  [{second\\child}]
  ]
  \end{forest}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]